# Get CategoryId of the table on Selected value in the Second table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, excel

I have dropdownlist for the categories. I want that when a user selects the categories and then he has to upload a excel sheet into a table. So I want that for whatever Id he selects and uploads the sheet, its Id should get copied in the column of the table. I have pulled the categories in the dropdownlist .Just need how to copy the ID of the selectedValue from the list.

Please see the Code of fetching the category in a dropdown:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from dbo.CategoriesForMerchant where ParentId is null", conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddlCategories.DataSource = dr;
        ddlCategories.Items.Clear();
        ddlCategories.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
        ddlCategories.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
        ddlCategories.DataBind();
        ddlCategories.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Category--", "0"));
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I have the Second table with the column name CategoryId also.

Please help.
Any help would be great

Comment: use dropdown selectedindexchanged events.

Comment: are you storing excel file in sql table?

Comment: @Sandeep: yes, you are right

Comment: @NadeemKhan when upload button is clicked get ddlCategories.SelectedValue and excel file bytes and store it to table in which you want store

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
protected void ddlCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a=ddlCategories.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: I will try this, but how to copy this int a in the Column of the sql table